# Must laptops be in checked luggage flying Istanbul to USA through Toronto?

Tags: air-travel, usa, airport-security

Wen traveling through Istanbul to the USA, laptops must be put into checked baggage. If my first stop on the North American continent is Toronto, is this still the case?

Answer (score 11):

No. The ban is literally for flights bound to the USA not for travellers who might end up in the USA. The only Canadian flight affected by the ban is Royal Jordanian's Amman-Montreal because it stops in Detroit first.